# The difference between these 2 XPath queries

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I don't understand why we should use text() instead of just using "."
What is the difference?

```
//library/book/author[text() = "An Author"]
```

vs

```
//span[@class="whateverclass"][. = "An Author"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is probably best illustrated with an example, where an element has one or more child elements, and multiple text elements (an element is allowed multiple text elements interspersed between child elements):

```
<element>
  text1
  <child>
     child1text1
  <child>
  text2
</element>
```

Assuming `element` is current:

- **`.`** will return `text1 child1text1 text2` (with whitespace)
- **`text()[1]`** will return `text1`
- **`text()[2]`** will return `text2`

Of special note is `text()` will behave differently in xslt 1.0 vs xslt 2.0

- **`text()`** returns just `text1` in xslt 1.0
- **`text()`** returns `text1 text2` (with whitespace) in xslt 2.0

Comment: The node set/sequence selected by `text()` is the same in both xpath 1.0 and 2.0 (it's a sequence of two text nodes), the difference is in the way this sequence is converted to a string.  Even in xpath 2.0 `element[text() = 'text1 text2']` would not match this `element` because there is no single node in the sequence that has that string value.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for the clarification - can I confirm that the reason for the difference is due to differences in string serialization of result tree fragments (1) vs node-set (2)?

Comment: Not really.  The difference is because in XSLT 1.0 when you say `<xsl:value-of select="foo"/>` and `foo` is a node set containing more than one node the result is the string value of just the first node in the set, whereas in XSLT 2.0 it's the concatenation of the string values of _all_ the nodes separated by spaces.

Answer (score 2):

`.` gives you the text of the current node and all childnodes

`text()` gives you the text of the current node only

conclusion: use `text()` if you want to check text in a node because with `.` you will check the text of all potential childnodes too

Answer (score 2):

`.` is a node set containing a single node, the current context node (the `span` element node in your example).  The string value of this is the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes, so if you had

```
<span class="whateverclass">Ann <b>A.</b> Author</span>
```

this would be the string `"Ann A. Author"` (without the quotes).

`text()` is a node set containing all the immediate child text nodes of the context node (two nodes `"Ann "` and `" Author"` in the example above).  An `=` comparison where one side is a node set and the other is a string is true if *any* of the nodes have the given string value, so the above example `<span>` element would match any of the patterns

```
span[@class='whateverclass'][. = 'Ann A. Author']
span[@class='whateverclass'][text() = 'Ann ']
span[@class='whateverclass'][text() = ' Author']
```

but would *not* match `[text() = 'Ann A. Author']`

Answer (score 2):

You should normally NOT use text(). Using "." assembles the string value, ignoring comments and processing instructions, while text() can give you the text split up into several pieces based on where the comments appeared. Only use text when you want to handle mixed content one piece at a time.